# add rows in pandas with values from a linear regression based on other rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, linear-regression

I have a dataframe with two columns `Date_of_journey` and `Price`. The column `Date_of_journey` takes values between 1 and 119 but it has only 37 rows. So a lot of dates are missing.

Is there a simple way to add those dates where the price is somewhere in between the previous and next row?

Here is a plot of the data to give you an idea. I would like to add a row with `Date_of_journey=4` and `5` with a Price that fits the gray curve. [image]

Comment: Make Date_of_Journey your index with `set_index`, then `reindex` over the range you want, and finally `interpolate` the Price column with your desired method/assumptions

Comment: Can you please elaborate on how to ```interpolate``` the ```Price```?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could resample your `pd.DataFrame` to a new range using `RangeIndex()` and interpolate between the known values using [`pd.interpolate(method='linear')`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.interpolate.html). With more data you 'll get a plot similar to yours.

```
import pandas as pd
import io

data = """Date_of_Journey   Price
1   24089.333333
3   14873.397727
6   14035.232877
9   13178.641509
15  5785.500000"""

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data), delimiter='\t', index_col='Date_of_Journey')
df = df.reindex(pd.RangeIndex(start=1, stop=119,step=1))
df.interpolate(method='linear', inplace=True)

df.plot(y='Price')
```

**Output:**
[image: Plot based on 5 datapoints]